# Qt and Qt application prerequisites

Tags: qt, deployment

I am new to Qt, and I am working in Windows 7.

When I try to run my application directly, I see an error about missing some DLLs. I tried to fix them, but I could not (I tried to build statically).

Is there any correct solution?

My question is:

If I want to run my Qt application on other computers, what do I need? For example, for a .NET application we need to install the .NET framework on the target computer, but what about for Qt?

I searched for its SDK and found a SDK that was about 1.6 GB! Does this mean every time I want to install my application I should install a 1.6 GB sized SDK? That's far too bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to distribute your application with needed libraries.
If your application is running on Windows you can follow this guide: [Deploying an Application on Windows](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/windows-deployment.html). You can find needed libraries as dll in bin directory inside SDK. A basic Qt gui application needs at least **QTCORE4.DLL**, **QTGUI4.DLL** and, if you are using Qt Creator, **MINGWM10.DLL**. You can leave these libraries in the same directory as you application.

Comment: i found these files,and put them in same directory as my application execute file,but steel an error occured

Comment: what error? adding these files changed something? Maybe you are using other modules (network, xml...) or image plugins (png, jpeg...)

Comment: aaaaa no,just a very simple app,but i add the bin path to my path environment variable,and every thing goes right ;-)

Comment: adding bin path to your environment variable PATH wont make your application working in other computers

Comment: exactly.this is my concern yet.but coping the ddls did not fix my problem.what can i do?

Comment: Remove qt from environment variable and add step by step needed libraries. What is the error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5598/discussion-between-alessandro-pezzato-and-ali-foroughi)

Answer (score 1):

You can't link statically against Qt unless you have built the libraries in that configuration (which you won't if you've just downloaded the pre-built SDK).  Be aware that if you do want to link statically there are licensing implications for some components.

If you have built a release configuration then you will need at least the libraries Alessandro mentioned, QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll.  Depending on the other parts of the library you're using you may also need QtXml4.dll QtWebkit4.dll, QtXmlPatterns4.dll and possibly Phonon.dll.  Check that you are building a release configuration rather than a debug configuration, as this won't run as it needs the Visual Studio debug runtimes, which you can't redistribute.  If you are in doubt which dlls you need then use [DependencyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to find out (note that this doesn't show Phonon.dll as it is loaded later).

Generally you'll only need about 4-6 of the dlls, you won't need the whole SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that many applications use Qt, you have some real chance the DLLs are already installed. Anyway, beware of MSVC dependencies: we had some real nightmare deploying applications on some server, partly related to a policy switch from VS2005 to VS2008. Alessandro already given a good resource: see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407319/qt-program-deploy-to-multi-platform-how) previous post.

Comment: If they are installed, they'd be "private" in the program that installed them, in their installation folder, so you can't rely on that and have to ship them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Qt5, besides the .dlls mentioned by the first answer, you must also add the platforms/ folder from the bin directory inside the SDK.