# qmake: clean way to copy qt dlls into output folder

Tags: qt, dll, copy

OK, I have read existing answers about this question.
But no one is tolerable.

See [how-to-copy-qt-runtime-dlls-to-project-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391964/how-to-copy-qt-runtime-dlls-to-project-output)

But $$QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT doesn't contain any dll files. All dlls are located in the "bin" directory in qt installation. On the other hand, QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT refers to "lib" directory.
So, this method doesn't work.

Do anybody have a working method of doing this thing?

Comment: This was [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output).

Answer (score 0):

I do

```
QMAKE_DLLDIR_QT = $$QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT/../bin
```

but since 5.0 they no longer define QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT
my quick solution is:

```
isEmpty(QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT) : {
    SPLITED=$$section(QMAKESPEC, "/", 0, -3)
    QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = $$SPLITED/lib
}
```

but 
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28901
suggest we should use other method

PS: LIBDIR contains static lirbaries used for linker